# Swift Observation framework and debounce

Tags: swiftui, combine, observation-framework

I am currently migrating some SwiftUI code from combine to the new observation framework and I want to know how I can I maintain debounce? Is there anyway to natively debounce from within the Observation framework?

I have tried combining Combine ~no pun intended~ with the Observation framework and it produces a slew of errors.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample that demonstrates the "slew of errors"?  The Observer mechanism in the SwiftUI framework, and Combine, are not replacements for one another so replacing one with the other may not be appropriate in all cases.

Comment: Meaning I wanted an idiomatic way to debounce code when using the Observer macro, right now it appears as if you can only debounce from the old mechanism using combine, did apple include a way to do this from the Observer macro?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no debounce because the `Observer` mechanism is designed for the synchronous delivery of information.

Debouncing involves a delay and therefore, by its very nature, is concerned with the asynchronous delivery of information. As such, debounce would be out-of-place in the `Observer` mechanism.

`Combine` is for handling asynchronous messages and debounce is appropriate in that system.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to debounce, you can use this code :

```swift
public actor Debouncer {
    private let duration: Duration
    private var isPending = false
    
    public init(duration: Duration) {
        self.duration = duration
    }
    
    public func sleep() async -> Bool {
        if isPending { return false }
        isPending = true
        try? await Task.sleep(for: duration)
        isPending = false
        return true
    }
}
```

Put this code in your Observable:

```swift
    private let debouncer = Debouncer(duration: .seconds(0.5))

    func checkEmailValidity() async {
        guard await debouncer.sleep() else { return }
        
        ... do your debounced stuff here ...
    }
```

And somewhere on your SwiftUI View for example:

```swift
    .onChange(of: viewModel.email) { Task { await viewModel.checkEmailValidity() } }
```

Comment: This is not a debounce. I 2 changes come in fast, then the second one will be never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need debounce in SwiftUI because all state changes are debounced already, that is you can set the state many times but `body` will only be called once afterwards. Combine's `ObservableObject` matches this behaviour by sending `objectWillChange` to SwiftUI instead of didChange which would be too late for debouncing.

However if you really need debounce, e.g. for your model or networking layers, then there is a `debounce` in the AsyncAlgorithms Swift package [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Debounce.md).

In Xcode choose File->Add Package Depdendencies and choose AsyncAlgorithms.

Comment: Can you provide an example how this is achieved using the AsyncAlgorithm framework?

Comment: its iOS 16+, so most of us cant use it.